# Why are there mistakes? What should I do?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

There is something wrong with `this.name`,what should I do？

TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'NumberPropertyNames'.

```
type NumberPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }[keyof T];

class User{
  uid:1;
  name:NumberPropertyNames<this>
  login(){
    this.name = 'uid';
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the goal that you are trying to accomplish here?  This seems like a really strange design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy you chose this community. We will always help you. Your Numbered properties are a good attempt but you should use `as` operator.

```
type NumberPropertyNames<T> = keyof {[P in keyof T as T[P] extends number ? P : never]: T[P]};
```

This feature is not good documented but for understanding what mapped types are, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types.

Then, don't use this type. Use the User type.

```
type NumberedPropertiesInUser = NumberPropertyNames<User>;
// you will see IntelliSense in VS Code - press Ctrl and enter mouse to type NumberedPropertiesInUser
```

[image: IntelliSense]

But you cannot use it directly in User - it will be a cycle. (Try it yourself, if you don't know what it is.) So you can copy User without the name property and then use that copy.

The whole working code looks like this:

```
type NumberPropertyNames<T> = keyof {[P in keyof T as T[P] extends number ? P : never]: T[P]};
type NumberedPropertiesInUser = NumberPropertyNames<User>;
interface UserCopy extends Omit<User, "name"> {};
// Omit deletes a property or more when you use union like "a" | "b".
class User {
    uid: 1;
    name: NumberPropertyNames<UserCopy>;
    login() {
        this.name = 'uid';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Can't I use this? Because I want to make inherited classes work. 
```class Login extends User{
  data:1

  test(){
    this.name = 'data'
  }
}
```

Comment: Inheriting, it should work, because you won't add any number property. If you will do so, create Login copy like `interface LoginCopy extends Omit<Login, "name"> {}`.